# What is the difference between spring component and bean's scope?

Tags: java, spring, components, javabeans

Component is used in class level definition by `@Component` annotation where Bean is used in construction or method level definition by `@Bean` annotation. @Component are used to auto-detect and auto-configure beans using classpath scanning. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

`@Component` can be used for , the spring to automatically find the bean and register to the context.

`@Bean` - Its our responsibility to provide the instantiation implementation for the particular bean.

Answer (score 0):

Both annotations are used for defining Spring managed beans.

You use `@Component` to define a bean outside of a `@Configuration`. You apply the annotation on top of the class that defines the component.

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

}
```

You use `@Bean` to define a bean within a `@Configuration`. You apply the annotation on top of the method that creates the bean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyComponent myComponent() {
        return new MyComponent();
    }

}
```